# Can passengers visit the flight attendants' sleeping quarters?

Tags: aircraft, cabin-crew

On modern airplanes cabin crew apparently have their own sleeping quarters. See this [Youtube Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sg-WqBrKoTQ). Can you peek inside these cabins as a passenger or is that off-limits?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Airlines' rules clearly indicate that the crew rest areas are only to be used by the crew members, you usually find placards stating that on the doors to these areas. Anyway that doesn't mean it is not possible. These areas are not considered to be high risk areas or so, they contain bunks, emergency equipment and in some cases a seat or two. You can ask the cabin crew nicely and they will let you take a peek. I have let curious passengers do that myself many times. On the other hand, the crew rest areas for cockpit crew are off the limits and no one is allowed there even cabin crew, that's due to many reasons one of them is they are usually located next to the cockpit itself or in some cases the entrance to it can share the same door with the cockpit.

Now, here are some of the aircraft that have these rest areas:

- **777-200**: they are called **LCRC** or lower crew rest compartment and contain 6 bunks usually. This is one of the ugliest crew rest areas, this compartment is a removable cargo compartment which can be installed or removed depending on the flight and crew legality. These compartments are tight and not usable on ground, you need to open a hatch on the floor to access it, the air flow will only start after take off, they are also usually hot. I personally hate them and I prefer a passenger seat over them. They are located next to R3 door (middle of the airplane, right side) and the access door is visible to passengers, it will be hard for the crew to let you go in. Also, it requires a key to open it.
- **777-300** : they are called **OFAR** or (overhead flight attendant rest area) and contain 8 bunks usually. They are so beautiful and big in size. Also bunks are big and makes you feel like home. The access door is located in front of L5 door (aft of the airplane, left side). The door needs a combination to be opened and only the crew know it. This will be easy for the crew to let you in, since no passengers will be able to see you when you are going up.
- **747-400**: are one of the first planes to provide a designated cabin crew rest areas. They are located aft of R5 door (aft right side of the plane). They contain 6-8 bunks usually, sometimes two seats as well. It is large and well ventilated.
- **A380**: it has two rest areas for the cabin crew. One located in the middle and one at the back. It can also have three (depending on the airline).

Remember, ask the cabin crew after the last service in the flight, because after the last service usually no more rest times for the cabin crew and the bunks will be empty. Ask nicely and for sure they will let you see it.

Comment: Last year I flew the A380 on Emirates to Amsterdam; since this was my first "long" flight on the A380 (the previous one was from Dubai to Kuwait and I didn't get a chance to talk to the crew); I asked them various questions. Have to say, the crew was very friendly and frank. I asked about the rest quarters on longer flights and universally the crew said that they preferred the 777-300 rest areas over the A380 as they were too cramped. One even said that the A380 is great for passengers, not so great for crews.

Answer (score 9):

The crew rest areas are out of bounds to anyone other than operating crew. I have worked for two of the largest UK scheduled airlines and that was the case with both of them.  No offence, but this is the only place crew can go to have a rest from passengers and there's no way I'd agree to letting a passenger 'have a peek', even if it was permitted. It's the crew's private space and that should be respected - you wouldn't go into a shop or any other public place and expect to have a peek in their staff room.

Comment: No offense, but I rather fly with airlines where flight attendents see the passengers as equal and as a resilt don't need a rest from them.

Comment: @user141: have you ever worked retail or a similar public-facing job?  Even when you see and treat your customers (clients, students, colleagues…) as equals, you can still need a break from them at times during the working day.

Comment: Absolutely out of bounds. Crew are instructed on this. Crew rest is a legal requirement per the country's airline operating orders and treated accordingly. Not to say some friendly crew might let you take a peek, but I've never heard of them doing this, and certainly not during the flight.